Landscape Server and Defender for Endpoint
Does Landscape server support Defender for Endpoint?
I'm unable to find any documentation related to this topic.

You're asking if an Ubuntu product supports a Microsoft solution. Since it's not documented anywhere, I'd say the answer is most likely no

Thank you @ArturMeinild for your response.
